# ArcGIS 10.2.1 projection Issue - Everything shifted west 50 m

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, coordinate-system

I just completed hand-digitizing features on some NAIP (NAD83) imagery as a shapefile (NAD83...or that's what I thought I was doing). The coordinate system for the dataframe was NAD83, but now when I re-add the layer everything is shifted to the west by almost excactly 50 meters. I've tried projecting the data and redefining the projections between NAD83 and NAD27, but no luck. I'm used to seeing a N-S shift between NAD83 and NAD27, but can't for the life of me figure out what is causing the east-west shift. Anyone have any ideas...I tried making a new project and seeing if that could be the issue, but it still doesn't line up.

Comment: Can you verify that the datum of the shapefile (not the dataframe) is NAD83? By the way, if you are not familiar with the differences between datums and coordinate systems, it would help to read up on it.

Comment: Datum of the shapefile is North American 1983 as is the dataframe and the imagery. The weird thing is that I did this same thing yesterday for a different year's imagery and I don't have any problems. I was hoping the 50 m shift to the west might be a clue. Obviously I mucked something up, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: I'm not sure what the cause of the problem is, but if you're using ArcGIS you can use the "Move" edit tool (http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001t0000002m000000.htm) to move it back to where it should be. You should edit your question to include what software and version you are using.

Comment: Good tip and thanks! That fixed the issue...not sure what the root of the problem was but everything lines up correctly now.

Comment: What specific projection is the imagery in? What specific projection are you editing in? Seems unlikely that the imagery is in unprojected NAD83.

Comment: The imagery is projected as NAD83 and datum is N.A. 1983.

Comment: *Just* NAD83 isn't a projected CRS, it's Geographic. The NAIP imagery should be in UTM Zone x on the NAD83 datum. It would be helpful to post the *exact* text of the Coordinate system tab in naming what CRS your layers/dataframe are set to. The only thing I really see that might have happened here is the image being reprojected on the fly to GCSNAD83 from its UTM zone, but I wouldn't expect a shift of exactly 50m west from that. Without more detail about the exact steps/settings when you first set up and added things and started digitizing, it's hard to determine what may have gone wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the cause of the problem is, but if you're using ArcGIS you can use the "Move" edit tool (help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//…) to move it back to where it should be.

Comment: As I commented above...this is a good work around. Now if I could just figure out what the root of the problem was. For now it fixed the issue.

Comment: Definitely update here if you discover the cause of the problem. It could save someone else some pain!